# Timeout function for user input on 4x4 membrane keypad with pad4pi

Tags: python, python-3

I'm making a python script for a 4x4 keypad that's connected to a raspberry pi where the user enters a 4 pin code and the program tells the user whether or not it's correct. In order to take in the input from the keypad I'm using this python library called pad4pi(python 3 version) and it's almost done except for one part, I want to implement a timeout function so that if the user doesn't press any buttons on the keypad within a certain time frame(ie 5 seconds), the program resets the code variable which stores all the numbers the user enters from the keypad and starts over with the pin code entering process.

Here is the code:

```
from pad4pi import rpi_gpio
import time


# Setup Keypad
KEYPAD = [
        ["1","2","3","A"],
        ["4","5","6","B"],
        ["7","8","9","C"],
        ["*","0","#","D"]
]

# same as calling: factory.create_4_by_4_keypad, still we put here fyi:
ROW_PINS = [11, 9, 0, 5] # BCM numbering
COL_PINS = [6, 13, 19, 26] # BCM numbering

factory = rpi_gpio.KeypadFactory()

keypad = factory.create_keypad(keypad=KEYPAD, row_pins=ROW_PINS, col_pins=COL_PINS)


code=""#the numbers that user enters will be appended to this variable
pin="0126"#this is the correct pin code, the code variable is compared to this variable

def doKey(key):

  global code
  global pin
  code += key




  if (len(code) == len(pin)):
    if(code == pin):
      print('correct code')
      code=""
    else:
      print("Invalid code")
      code=""


# doKey will be called each time a keypad button is pressed
keypad.registerKeyPressHandler(doKey)


try:
  while(True):
    time.sleep(0.2)
except:
 keypad.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a counter which you will increment in your `while(True)` loop, and reset to zero in the keypad handler. Once the counter reaches `5s / 0.2s = 25`, you will reset the user-entered `code` to zero before adding new digits to it.